# Pass markup to lightning-modal dynamically in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

I've a LWC which defines generic structure of Modal using `lightning-modal-*`standard Base components.

myModal.cmp

```
<lightning-modal-header label={modalLabel}></lightning-modal-header>

<lightning-modal-body>
    .. Get HTML markup Dynamically from calling component
</lightning-modal-body>

<lightning-modal-footer>
   
</lightning-modal-footer>
```

I use below code snippet to open the modal in the calling component:

callingComponent.js

`MyModal.open({size: 'medium',description: '---'});`

Here, how can I pass modal body (in HTML markup form) dynamically to myModal.cmp?

Comment: Check out [slots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots). This won't handle literally dynamic HTML that is being generated at runtime (this is a potential security issue anyway), but allows you to pass the content from a parent component "into" the child component when that child defines one or more slots.

Comment: Thanks Phil! But in this case, I'm opening modal using MyModal.open({size: 'medium',description: '---'}); So within open(), how can I pass slots?